# css problems with parent and child, content background wont layout correctly

Tags: css, layout, html

I am building the content section of my web site, and I wanted to do a test to make sure I could put things side by side using float:left, right etc... On my web site I was able to get 2 boxes next to one another, but the background container the boxes are in wont center on 1000px's and fill up the whole content background. Once you look at my site you will understand...I know the problem is in my css, please help. The rest of my site I contained with a background that was 100% then inside that I made containers that were 1000px. I dont know why it is not working now because it worked with the top banner and the menubar. THANKS AS ALWAYS!

site:

http://www.nestudiosonline.com/test.php

html:

```
<div id="contentbackground">
    <div id="content">
    <div id="flashbanner"></div><div id="test"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
@charset "utf-8";

#contentbackground
{
width:100%;
height:auto;
margin-top:0px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
margin-right:0px;
padding-top:0px;
padding-left:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
padding-right:0px;
border:0
}

#content
{
background-color:#FFF;
/* for IE */
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
filter:alpha(opacity=80);
/* CSS3 standard */
opacity:.8;
width:1000px;
height:auto;
margin-top:0px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-bottom:0px;
margin-right:auto;
padding-top:10px;
padding-left:5px;
padding-bottom:5px;
padding-right:5px;
border:solid;
border-width:1px
}

#flashbanner
{
float:left;
display:inline;
width:500px;
height:200px;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
border:solid;
border-width:1px
}

#test
{
float:right;
width:400px;
height:200px;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
border:solid;
border-width:1px
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand correctly, but putting `overflow: hidden` on your `#content` should make everything cool.

EDIT: and also a `clear: both` on the same element.

EDIT: I applied these changes in Firebug and it seems to work fine.

Comment: excuse me but what is firebug, im a real newb at web design. i used to do it back in the day. thanks for the help sir.

Comment: yay it worked, only problem now is that the content div isnt sizing up correctly, for example the banner at the top is inside a container thats 100% and then i made a div for the banner that was 1000px, i did the same for the content div but not aligning up..

Comment: Firebug is a tool for Firefox, you can do a lot of useful things with it. I checked the site, it seems to me you have not applied these two things (overflow, clear), and I don't really understand your problem, sorry.

Comment: i didnt upload the file yet thats why you do not see it but ill upload it now, they only problem i have is theres a small gap between the menu bar and the content area.

Comment: i got it, it was a problem with my links heights..thanks so much for the help. I need to read up about that clear function i have no idea what it does, overflow hidden as well. thanks again. check it out u will see what i was talking about.

Comment: should i always use oveflow:hidden and the clear:both after i use float?

Comment: Use overflow: hidden on the container which has floated elements inside, so it will take up all the space taken by the floated elements. Use clear where you want any previous floats to stop having an effect.

Comment: How come if I try to make the two boxes have white background they still get affected by the parent element, and have opacity? I thought that by declaring they had a white background they would be show up solid. i dont want them to have opacity too.

Comment: You will certainly find an existing answer to this here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I figured it out, I was about to start doing absolute positioning etc..but it was as easy as using a 24bit png image in the background of the content div. check it out tell me what you think sir.

Answer (score 0):

First add `overflow:hidden;` for `#linksbackground` and `#content`. Then you have to understand that you have set the background on your body, so this behavior is logical. To achieve what you want, you need to create a wrapper div, under below the `body` tag, and close it before the `</body>` . Give an id `#wrapper` for this div and add the following properties

```
#wrapper {
    background: url("../images/olddkeshant3.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

then remove the background from the `#bodybackground`.

To position the background in a specific position you can change the above values `0 0` in the background property to anything that fit your needs.

> A percentage X aligns the point X%
>   across (for horizontal) or down (for
>   vertical) the image with the point X%
>   across (for horizontal) or down (for
>   vertical) the element's padding box.
>   For example, with a value pair of '0%
>   0%',the upper left corner of the image
>   is aligned with the upper left corner
>   of the padding box. A value pair of
>   '100% 100%' places the lower right
>   corner of the image in the lower right
>   corner of the padding box. With a
>   value pair of '14% 84%', the point 14%
>   across and 84% down the image is to be
>   placed at the point 14% across and 84%
>   down the padding box.

source: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-position

Comment: I think your confused. I do have a wrapper on my background, I just didnt put the css for it because all of my page works fine except for the new content area i just started...if you click on my site link you see that the content background div that i made partially transparent is not aligning like the rest of the page, its bulking out and it wont expand down. The two boxes you see are supposed to be in that content area...

Comment: the transparent background doesn't show because you don't clear the floats. If you add the overflow:hidden will show it. About the alignment I don't see any problem. It works as it supposed according your code. Be more specific on this

Comment: overflow:hidden did the trick but i still have 1 problem, theres a small space between the content box and the menu, its like 1px. i dont know why

Comment: I don't see something. The content box it's exactly under the menu's border